# How to deal with many dynamic image requests to the server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm dynamically appending an html string to a container using jquery.

```
$('#container').append(str);

str = '<div class="images"><img src = "http://imgs.com/x></div>
       <div class="images"><img src = "http://imgs.com/y></div>
       <div class="images"><img src = "http://imgs.com/z></div>
       <div class="images"><img src = "http://imgs.com/n></div>';
```

When this html string is appended it will make four requests to http://imgs.com/ for images x,y,z,b.

I'm trying to get all four images in one request.  And I want to store all for images and use them later.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

To download all of your image files in one request you would need to create a sprite.  A sprite contains several images concatenated together into one larger image.  When displaying an image the sprite is used as background of an element and then the background is positioned to the coordinates of the desired image within the sprite.

Aside from using the sprite tactic, a browser will always download these images via one request per image.

Further Reading:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: But I need the images dynamically, so its not always images x,y,z.  It could be images x,a,t and the next request is for x,p,q.  Is it possible to make sprites dynamically?

Comment: ...and there could be thousands of images.